# How is use "422 Unprocessable Entity (WebDAV)" or any other custom http status code in golang

Tags: http, go

The go http package only supports the status code from RFC 2616. A lot of REST apis like github use 422 for bad input data. I would like to also do this, but I don't see a good way of doing this in go. The options I see are

1. Edit the source code to the http package and add it. This would be easy to do but would be bad to edit a core library.
2. The http.Response struct has Status as a string StatusCode as an int. I think I could just set them in the responsce, but the http.Handler only has a RespnseWriter interface. It might be possible to make a http.Transport that has a RoundTripper that correctly sets the Response. Even if it is possible this seem like it would be a hacky to some degree.

So what is the best way of adding a custom http status code to go, or is it just a bad idea?

Comment: What makes you thin you cannot use arbitrary status codes? Why not just call WriteHeader(422) on your ResponseWriter?

Comment: If you do that the http response looks like "HTTP/1.1 422 status code 422". I would like it to be "HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity"

Comment: I think its worthwhile, but I also think you're correct that there's no easy way to do it right now. You need to be able to add an entry to this map:

http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/status.go?h=statusText

Maybe submit a feature request, and just patch the library for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of status codes including 422 were added in go 1.7

https://github.com/golang/go/commit/b9ec0024fbc18dd94eff7240afd82fac6b4d8fdc

Answer (score 2):

As the status `422 Unprocessable Entity` is a WebDAV extension, you can use the package [`golang.org/x/net/webdav`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/webdav) and handle it correctly:

```
http.Error(w,
    webdav.StatusText(webdav.StatusUnprocessableEntity),
    webdav.StatusUnprocessableEntity)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can plug the status code in manually as a parameter of of `http.Error()`:

```
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    http.Error(w, "Some Response Text", 422)
    return
}
```

This will return status 422 and the response "Some Response Text"

[Here](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Error) is a link to this function in the docs.

Comment: http.Error just adds the string as a body to the HTTP response and the response line looks like "HTTP/1.1 422 status code 422" not "HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity".